# Configure OWASP ZAP and ZScaler

Tags: docker, zap, zscaler

I want to set up ZAP in a local Docker container and call the ZAP API via a web app that provides a custom UI to ZAP and which is also hosted on the container (local meaning my laptop is not on our corporate network and the Docker instance is running locally on my laptop) BUT I want to target a web app in our data center.

How do I configure ZAP (having been configured as a local proxy to my browser) to pass the requests it receives to ZScaler? So the call chain is browser to local host to ZAP to ZScaler to target app in DC.